# Jquery fade in array of objects in JSON list

Tags: javascript, json, animation, jquery-animate, var

I have this code:

```
var $question = $("<p>").text(result['question']).hide()
                           .delay(4000*i).fadeIn(0);
                           $("<p>").hide();
$('#output').append($question);
```

}

how can i hide the first item showed?
complete code here http://jsfiddle.net/Qf3FZ/

Comment: Please remove the java tag, this is javascript (a completely different language)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Active').find('span:first-of-type').fadeOut(300);
```

JQuery remembers which method you hide/show object. If you use .fadeIn() to show object, then you must use .fadeOut() to hide this object.

Comment: Please add some description about how/why this code solves the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Description explaining how this will solve the problem would be helpful.

Comment: JQuery remember which method you hide/show object.
If you use .fadeIn() to show object, then you must use .fadeOut() to hide this object.